# How to monitor input in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension for chrome that should check input fields in a form using REGEX

To do this, I need to get an input field, I do it as follows:

```
let input = document.getElementById("id_input");
```

After that, I have to add some function that whenever there is any change in the input, it applies a Regex in the value, formatting it in real time if the user enters some invalid value.

I tried to make a sketch of this code as follows:

```
input.addEventListener("change", function () {
    let v = document.getElementById('search').value;
    v.replace(/world/g, "universe");
});
```

For some reason it's not working, I don't have as much knowledge in javascript and I don't know if the code I made is wrong or if I need to add something else to it.

Comment: This code will not update the element's value. It'll not even change `v`. Use `const searchInput = document.getElementById('search');` then `searchInput.value = searchInput.value.replace(/world/g, "universe");` (the reason is that v is just a string, and even if the replace function did change the string in place ([it doesn't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)), it still wouldn't update the input because that association is gone)

Comment: You are getting the value of the element, but you are not updating the element itself, not even the variable v. You are only using the method/function. I think you should try to update the value with something like ```document.getElementById('search').value = document.getElementById('search').value.replace(/world/g, "universe");```

Comment: Also, for real time change use `input` event, not `change`.